# TimerTask run/cancel with url call?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have one admin panel with login form. Inside panel I can create/run TimerTask when I call url /starttask/ and that is all good. But i want also to shutdown(cancel) my TimerTask when I call  url /shutdowntask/ and that is also ok if I stay logged in inside panel, because I can catch reference of the TimerTask over the session. But if I run my task and if I logout from the panel than I will kill my session and I will klill reference of the TimerTask object, so next time when I logged in I can not shutdown my TimerTask when I call url /shutdowntask/. Is there any static class for controlling TimerTask or some manager where I can get reference of the created TimerTask object without my session? TimerTask will run every 1h forever and I want to control over the url? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Before the TimerTask's run method,you can set a flag. eg: if the flag is true, execute the run method else don't execute the run method.

Comment: Ok but again I will lose reference of the created object?